# Push notification not received from Sinch, via web-app

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, sinch

The setup is as following: Website using JS-SDK (currently the Sinch web sample) will call an iPad app (which might be running in the background).

I have generated and uploaded a PKCS 12 development certificate to the Sinch Dashboard. I am able to manually send push notifications to the app with Pusher (using the same PKCS 12 certificate).

However, when calling from my website the app does not receive any push notifications. `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is not being called.

I was also unable to receive calls when using the iOS sample SinchCallinPush project, using the correct application and secret key, and the host set to `sandbox.sinch.com`

> By adding the line `[_client startListeningOnActiveConnection];` I am able to receive calls in the foreground

---

I have no idea where to continue searching for possible problems, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you enabled the Push notification capability? Have you enabled `Remote Notifications` and `background refresh` in `Background modes`? Have you registered for push notifications? Are you receiving a push notification token? Do you send the push notification to the API?

Comment: I have enabled all those capabilities. I am able to receive push notifications if I send them myself.

I am using Sinch's JS-SDK, and as far as I have tested, it does not send a push to the app.

Comment: It seems that Push Notifications have not been configured correctly on your app. Have a read through this tutorial for push notifications: https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started and this tutorial for user notifications in ios 10: https://www.appcoda.com/ios10-user-notifications-guide/

Comment: I might not have been clear enough, but push notifications work if I send them manually. I am able to send and receive push notifications if I use an external program, in this case *Pusher*. The app uses PushKit

Comment: is it a voip cert or APNS? CAn you share the setup of sinch for push notification. With regular push certs that handler is not called if you are in background, only voip push enables you to process stuff in the background

Comment: I only have a APNs certificate, because I read that VoIP certificates are deprecated [(a post)](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50106). Also, I cannot find the VoIP capability in Xcode.

Comment: I want to add: 1) I genereated a VoIP certificate, which I uploaded to Sinch. However, VoIP capability is not an available option in Xcode. 2) I cannot get it to push with the JS-SDK web sample to iOS-SDK SinchCallingPush sample (with correct keys, as described above).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem between web and android app, configured to receive push notifications via firebase cloud messaging. If calling from web-app - push never arrives. If "pushing" manually via Post request OR calling from another android app, everything works as expected.

For now I have to use the workaround of waking up device with custom push message and starting startListeningOnActiveConnection - after that I can receive the call (and have to stopListening after some reasonable timeout)

Comment: I am also able to make calls from iOS app to iOS app with push notifications. Great to know someone else also experiences this problem.

Comment: May I ask how you handled the push? I went with that approach, but the app cannot receive incoming calls for about 10 seconds after `startListeningOnActiveConnection` (this might be an iOS issue). Any information is greatly appreciated

Comment: yes, I think it is something ios specific. I just call startListeningOnActiveConnection and then stopListeningOnActiveConnection after about 60 sek. In this period I'm able to receive calls

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer, however this is not documented within Sinch Docs but I found out while exploring the Sinch Web SDK minified JS.

You just need to enable support for push notification while initialising the application capabilities.

```
sinchClient = new SinchClient({
applicationKey: 'xyz...',
capabilities: { calling: true, video: true },
supportActiveConnection: true,
supportManagedPush: true, //this is the piece of code which will enable push for you
//Note: For additional loging, please uncomment the three rows below
onLogMessage: function (message) {
    console.log(message);
},});
```

p.s. This will send the notification with a default payload that is not very useful atleast for me

The payload at iOS side looks like below

```
2020-05-13 01:36:31.823787+0500 SinchVideoCallKit[21670:8839367] didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload: {
aps =     {
    alert =         {
        "loc-key" = "SIN_INCOMING_CALL";
    };
};
sin = "AgEBN0Jb18/KQja0K04exxxxx...==";}
```

I haven't found a way as of now to pass custom headers from Web in the push notifications payload.